How to show FCM background notification based on message title?
I'm making a flutter app(Android) using fcm.
And I want to send a notification to the client app only when a message's title is "attendance".
I try to use if-else statement to solve it.
it works well in foreground but in the background, the if statement does not work.
This is forground message. it works well
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;

      if (notification != null) {
        String title = notification.title ?? "";
        String body = notification.body ?? "";
        
        // Show forground notification only in that condition 
        if (title == "attendance") {
          FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().show(
          notification.hashCode,
          title,
          body,

          // set details in Android
          const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'high_importance_channel',              
              'high_importance_notification',           
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.max,
            ),),
          );
        }
         else {
        }
      }
    });

This is background message handler. it doesnt' work
it shows notification whatever the title is
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 // Show Background notification only in that condition 
  if (message.notification?.title == "attendance") {
  final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(const AndroidNotificationChannel(     
          'high_importance_channel', 
          'high_importance_notification',
          importance: Importance.max,
      ));
  }
  else {
  }
}

please help me!!
It's my first time using fcm so I don't know much about it :(
I tried to implement it with an if-else conditional statement, but it works in the foreground, but not in the background.

Remove "notification" key value pair and add "content_available": true
It will look like this
{ 
    "to" : "...",
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": true,
    "data" : {
      ....
    }
}

This should send a silent notification.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

assuming you are not sending notification from firebase console

Thanks! I can solve it with your answer. Thank you so much.
